# while establishing connection in powerbi with hadoop am getting this error

Tags: hadoop, hive, powerbi

The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine.

I have given my server name ex.hadoop.ec2.mhjhjjokdkas

while trying to connect it shows the error.

we encountered an error while trying to connect.
Details:Details: "HDFS cannot connect to server 'sdsfhhhjkckjm'.The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine."